# How to add an item to an array of [500]][4] which is inside the while loop

Tags: c

I am reading a text file, which gives me 4 arguments from every line. suppose it's arg1, arg2,arg3,arg4. This while loops reads every line in the file and gives 4 arguments from every line till !feof. So, every time we get 4 arguments, I need to store it in a 2D array.... also how can I access it later?

I defined an array called `Wall[500][4]` (500 is just the large number that I took and 4 is the argument which we get each time).

then `wall[counter1][counter2] = {{arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4}}; c1++; c2++;`

```
double wall[500][4];
wall[counter1][counter2] = {{arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4}};
counter1++   
counter2++;
```

> error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
>
> ```
> wall[counter1][counter2] = {{arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4}};
> ```

Comment: *"I am reading a text file, which gives me 4 arguments from every line."* - Read them into the array; forget the middle man `arg`s. The syntax you seem to want to use doesn't work because arrays are not lvalues in C. Either directly assign each cell one at a time, or do as I suggested and read them from your file directly into your array slots.

Comment: @WhozCraig to be more accurate,An array is an lvalue, however it is a non-modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Can you show us the while-loop itself and how are you reading from file?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/owfxl4

Comment: So, i wanna add the arg1,2,3,4 to the array....

Comment: @WhozCraig i don't quite understand what you mean :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add values like that:

```
double wall[500][4];

wall[counter1][0] = arg1;
wall[counter1][1] = arg2;
wall[counter1][2] = arg3;
wall[counter1][3] = arg4;

counter1++;
```

Comment: cheers mate!! also, how can i access 4 elements at a time using for loop? do i use (i = 0; i < 500; i ++) and then inside it use i+4?

Comment: you can use another loop inside (int j = 0; j < 4; j ++)